# Firebase cloud messaging how to have 2 unique tokens for the same Android Studio project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM was sending notification to a random device every time with even though it was the same token, so it should have sent it to the same device every time.
FCM was working fine with one device, but when I added another device (with emulating it with Android studio) I started seeing that the notification would go to the unintended device at times, and I would always see that one of the tokens would get un-registered, and when I use one token the notification would arrive at any of the 2 devices. so my question is how to have 2 unique tokens where I can communicate and send my token to the device I select ?

I suspect that what is happening is that I can only get one Token and my 2 devices are actually sharing it, but I could be wrong.

Comment: do you have 2 unique tokens for the two separate devices?

Comment: Yes, each device has a different token

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not a bug, when I used a different computer I was able to get the right notification recipient every time, this tells me that it has to do with the fact that the first time the bug happened when I was using 2 devices from emulated from the same computer, but didn't happen when I used 2 separate computers to generate my notifications